# Dialog using Caliburn.Micro 4.0.x and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro 4.0.136-rc and want to display a dialog, asking for user input.

All I find is answers from several years ago, using classes which are not available in CM anymore. Others link to solutions on dead websites.

I'm using a ViewModel, which inherits from Screen. How can I create and display a Dialog using CM and MVVM?

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the answers from several years ago, using classes which are not available in CM anymore?

Comment: This is my top result when searching for Dialog and CM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510704/caliburn-showdialog-and-messagebox
The accepted answer is quite short, all links refer to dead websites. The next response uses WindowManager.ShowDialog(). This method can not be found.

Comment: Here's an updated link for that blog post that 404's: https://web.archive.org/web/20170113153246/http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/11/18/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6d-a-billy-hollis-hybrid-shell.aspx

Comment: And [this page](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition) has detailed information about how screens are composited.  Do a search on the page for `IDialogManager`.

Comment: Googling "Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens.zip" led me [here](https://github.com/anaisbetts/CaliburnMicro/tree/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens).  Granted, it may use some of your aforementioned missing classes, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the examples on the Internet do appear to be about ten years old.  http://kmees.github.io/blog/2011/06/16/mvvm-dialogs-with-caliburn-dot-micro/

Comment: Thats exactly my problem, all examples I find are outdated. Todays Caliburn.Micro doesn't offer an example of the referred HelloScreens anymore, as it dit in version 2.0.2.
4.0.x samples just use MessageBox.Show() like in this example: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/features/Features.CrossPlatform.Shared/Results/MessageDialogResult.cs
But an up-to-date example for an overlay like in https://vimeo.com/16975621 at 1:42 doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: Well, you don't need Caliburn Micro to display a dialog box with MVVM.

Comment: In any case, since we both agree that there aren't any readily available solutions that you can just drop into your project, your next best choice is to learn how to do it yourself.  There's more than enough material to accomplish this in the comments above, and when you're done you'll have a new skill.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 possible ways of displaying a dialog with Caliburn.Micro

## IWindowManager

Based on this page https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Caliburn.Micro/WindowManager/ShowDialog/php-windowmanager-showdialog-method-examples.html

I'm using IoC, so I injected IWindowManager to the ViewModel via constructor.

With this reference it's possible to call ShowDialogAsync() and point to the ViewModel from the dialog. Here is the important part:

```
        private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;

        public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            _windowManager = windowManager;
        }

        protected override async void OnViewLoaded(object view)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            await _windowManager.ShowDialogAsync(new UsrControlViewModel());
        }
```

## MaterialDesignInXAML

In my project the package MaterialDesignInXAML was already used, so this may not be acceptable for everyone.

Here is the documentation part for dialogs: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs

I found an issue describing how to show a dialog with MaterialDesignInXAML and that binding fails in Caliburn.Micro. While it seems to be an issue from Caliburn.Micro, Keboo provides a solution with a workaround.

Thread: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1085

From that thread, the important bit is:

ViewModel

```
public async Task OpenDialog()
{
    var viewModel = new UsrControlViewModel();
    UIElement uiElement = ViewLocator.LocateForModel(viewModel, null, null);
    ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewModel, uiElement, null);
    await DialogHost.Show(uiElement, 
    new DialogOpenedEventHandler((sender, args) => viewModel.WithDialogSession(args.Session)));
    var result = viewModel.Text;
}
```

View

```
    <materialDesign:DialogHost>
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <ContentControl />
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <!-- rest of my view -->
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

I will go with the second approach, since MaterialDesignInXAML is already in use in this project.

Comment: This is really good information that's hard to find. I have a Material Design / Caliburn.Micro app also and this is one of the hardest things I've had to work around. I ended up setting the DataContext for the View directly to work around this `UserView view = new UserView { DataContext = IoC.Get<UserViewModel>() }`. I like this method a lot better since it's native to Caliburn.Micro.